# group by first and last occurrence

Tags: mysql

I have a table like the following one:

```
    +-------------+--------------+
    | current_day | browser      |
    +-------------+--------------+
    | 2016-05-02  | Safari       |
    | 2016-05-03  | Safari       |
    | 2016-05-04  | Safari       |
    | 2016-05-05  | Safari       |
    | 2016-05-06  | Safari       |
    | 2016-05-07  | Safari       |
    | 2016-05-08  | Safari       |
    | 2016-05-09  | Opera        |
    | 2016-05-10  | Opera        |
    | 2016-05-11  | Opera        |
    | 2016-05-12  | Opera        |
    | 2016-05-13  | Opera        |
    | 2016-05-14  | Opera        |
    | 2016-05-15  | Chrome       |
    | 2016-05-16  | Firefox      |
    | 2016-05-17  | Firefox      |
    | 2016-05-18  | Firefox      |
    | 2016-05-19  | Firefox      |
    | 2016-05-20  | Firefox      |
    | 2016-05-21  | Firefox      |
    | 2016-05-22  | Firefox      |
    | 2016-05-23  | Safari       |
    | 2016-05-24  | Safari       |
    | 2016-05-25  | Safari       |
    | 2016-05-26  | Safari       |
    | 2016-05-27  | Safari       |
    | 2016-05-28  | Safari       |
    | 2016-05-29  | Safari       |
    | 2016-05-30  | Opera        |
    | 2016-05-31  | Opera        |
    | 2016-06-01  | Opera        |
    | 2016-06-02  | Firefox      |
    | 2016-06-03  | Firefox      |
    | 2016-06-04  | Firefox      |
    | 2016-06-05  | Firefox      |
    | 2016-06-06  | Firefox      |
    | 2016-06-07  | Firefox      |
    | 2016-06-08  | Firefox      |
    | 2016-06-09  | Chrome       |
    | 2016-06-10  | Chrome       |
    | 2016-06-11  | Chrome       |
    | 2016-06-12  | Chrome       |
    | 2016-06-13  | Chrome       |
    | 2016-06-14  | Chrome       |
    | 2016-06-15  | Chrome       |
    | 2016-06-16  | Chrome       |
    +-------------+--------------+
```

I would like to extract the first and last occurrence of each sequence in the 'browser' column, in other words the following result:

```
    +-------------+--------------+
    | current_day | browser      |
    +-------------+--------------+
    | 2016-05-02  | Safari       |
    | 2016-05-08  | Safari       |
    | 2016-05-09  | Opera        |
    | 2016-05-14  | Opera        |
    | 2016-05-15  | Chrome       |
    | 2016-05-16  | Firefox      |
    | 2016-05-22  | Firefox      |
    | 2016-05-23  | Safari       |
    | 2016-05-29  | Safari       |
    | 2016-05-30  | Opera        |
    | 2016-06-01  | Opera        |
    | 2016-06-02  | Firefox      |
    | 2016-06-08  | Firefox      |
    | 2016-06-09  | Chrome       |
    | 2016-06-16  | Chrome       |
    +-------------+--------------+
```

Is it possible/convenient to create a MYSQL query? Or is it better to extract all results and perform some post-processing with php?

Comment: You can use `min` and `max` on field ` current_day ` and ofcourse  `group by browser`

Comment: How do you order your source table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```sql
SELECT MIN(current_day) AS start_day, 
       MAX(current_day) AS stop_day, 
       browser
FROM (
   SELECT current_day, browser,
          @grp := IF(@br = browser, @grp,
                     IF(@br := browser, @grp+1, @grp+1)) AS grp
   FROM mytable 
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @grp := 0, @br := '') AS vars
   ORDER BY current_day) AS t
GROUP BY browser, grp
```

The above query uses variables, in order to identify islands of consecutive records having the same `browser` value. It returns a single row per browser.
You have to repeat the same subquery twice and use `UNION` if you want to get *two* separate lines for each of the min/max dates.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8311ce/1)

Comment: Cross join... Well played

Answer (score 1):

here are 2 samples for one and two lines per browser

**one line**

```
SELECT
  min(current_day) AS  start_date
  , max(current_day) AS end_date
  , browser
FROM your_table
GROUP BY browser;
```

**two lines**

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    min(current_day)
    , browser
  FROM your_table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    max(current_day)
    , browser
  FROM your_table
)
ORDER BY broser,current_day;
```

Comment: This returns wrong results if a `browser` is repeated in two separate regions, e.g. check `browser = 'Opera'`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT current_day, browser
FROM table_name AS a
WHERE current_day = (
    SELECT MAX(current_day)
    FROM table_name AS b
    WHERE a.browser = b.browser
) 
OR current_day = (
    SELECT MIN(current_day)
    FROM table_name AS c
    WHERE a.browser = c.browser
)
```

Slightly simpler method:

```
select min(current_day), max(current_day), browser from test group by browser;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT r.* FROM (SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT k.* FROM (SELECT * FROM `tbl_test` ORDER BY `current_day` DESC) as k GROUP BY k.browser) as t  UNION SELECT h.* FROM (SELECT q.* FROM (SELECT * FROM `tbl_test` ORDER BY `current_day` ASC) as q GROUP BY k.browser) as h ) as r ORDER BY r.current_day
```