# MySQL get first and last instance of each duplicate group

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL table as follows:

```
id, batch_id, cola, colb, colc, updated
```

`cola`, `colb` and `colc` can contain duplicate values and if any of that changes then it is not a duplicate group any more.

so lets suppose I have following values:

```
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2017-01-01 01:02:03
2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2017-01-01 01:02:04
3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2017-01-01 01:02:05
4, 4, 1, 0, 0, 2017-01-01 01:02:06
5, 5, 1, 0, 0, 2017-01-01 01:02:07
6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2017-01-01 01:02:08
7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 2017-01-01 01:02:09
8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 2017-01-01 01:02:10
9, 9, 1, 0, 0, 2017-01-01 01:02:11
10, 10, 1, 0, 0, 2017-01-01 01:02:12
11, 11, 1, 0, 0, 2017-01-01 01:02:13
```

As you can see above, this data has more than one duplicate groups.

I want to get the id of first and last instance of each duplicate group.
That would be:

```
1,
2,
3,
5,
6,
8
9,
11
```

The queries I have only returns the one single min and max Id per group.
i.e I Would only get

```
1,
3,
8,
11
```

The question here: [mysql: group by first and last occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37882795/mysql-group-by-first-and-last-occurrence) describes my problem much better, but the answer uses some variable foo that I dont understand and it only depends on 1 duplicate column, I have eight duplicate columns

And there are about 28 million records in the table...

Can anyone help me out?