# Get first and last instance detail from MySQL table in R

Tags: mysql, r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a table in MySql:

Table1:

```
ID    Initial_Date          Updated_Date         Sequence      Value_1   Value_2   Value_3   Value_4
I-1   2020-03-01 15:12:33   2020-03-01 15:12:33  1             10000     ABC       1.000     2.000
I-1   2020-03-01 15:12:33   2020-03-02 12:09:03  2             15000     xyz       1.500     3.000
I-2   2020-03-02 10:19:03   2020-03-02 10:19:03  1             11000     xyz       2.000     3.000
I-2   2020-03-02 10:19:03   2020-03-04 19:19:36  2             10000     ABC       1.000     3.000
I-2   2020-03-02 10:19:03   2020-03-05 10:12:43  1             15000     ABC       1.500     1.000
I-3   2020-03-01 15:12:33   2020-03-01 15:12:33  1             10000     ABC       1.000     2.000
```

Utilizing the above-mentioned table, I need to fetch the Initial and final values basis `Sequence` against each `ID` and want to identify what values got change between Initial and final record.

Where `F_Value` is final value against that prticular id.
`Day_diff` - Difference of days between Initial_Date and `Final_Date` in output data.

Required Output:

```
ID      Initial_Date         Final_Date           Day_diff   Count  Value_1  F_Value_1 Value_2   F_Value_2  Value_3 F_Value_3 Value_4  F_Value_4 
I-1     2020-03-01 15:12:33  2020-03-02 12:09:03  1          2      10000    15000     ABC       xyz        1.000   1.500     2.000     3.000
I-2     2020-03-02 10:19:03  2020-03-05 10:12:43  3          3      11000    15000     xyz       ABC        2.000   1.500     3.000     3.000
I-3     2020-03-01 15:12:33  2020-03-01 15:12:33  0          1      10000    10000     ABC       ABC      1.000    1.000    2.000     2.000
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql: group by first and last occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37882795/mysql-group-by-first-and-last-occurrence)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+ you can use `row_number()` to assign a number to each row partitioned by `id`. Once the number is according to the order by `sequence` ascending -- the first row per id gets `1` --, once descending the last row per id gets `1`. Put that in two derived tables you then join on common `id` and `row_number()`. In the `WHERE` clause filter for the `row_number()` to equal `1`. (If `sequence` is guaranteed to start with `1`, you can also use `sequence` directly instead of the `row_number()` in the ascending order of `sequence` since both are `1` for the first row then.)

To get the count you can use the windowed version of `count()` partitioned by `id`.

`datediff()` gets you the day between the first and last row of an `id`.

```
SELECT x1.id,
       x1.initial_date,
       x2.updated_date final_date,
       datediff(x2.updated_date, x1.initial_date) day_diff,
       x1.c count,
       x1.value_1,
       x2.value_1 f_value_1,
       x1.value_2,
       x2.value_2 f_value_2,
       x1.value_3,
       x2.value_3 f_value_3,
       x1.value_4,
       x2.value_4 f_value_4
       FROM (SELECT id,
                    initial_date,
                    count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) c,
                    value_1,
                    value_2,
                    value_3,
                    value_4,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                                       ORDER BY sequence ASC) rn
                    FROM table1) x1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT id,
                               updated_date,
                               value_1,
                               value_2,
                               value_3,
                               value_4,
                               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                                                  ORDER BY sequence DESC) rn
                               FROM table1) x2
                       ON x2.id = x1.id
                          AND x2.rn = x1.rn
       WHERE x1.rn = 1;
```

Comment: I have MySql Version `5.7.25-log`.